# C++ novice header file problem

Tags: c++, header

I am a beginner in c++ and I've a problem with header file management. I have a class, Matrix, with it's on .h and .cpp files. I've a second class, Map, with it's own .h and .cpp files too. Map.h includes Matrix.h, and so far it works. But when I go to code the implementation of Map (in Map.cpp) and I use stuff defined in Matrix.h, it gives me a undefined reference error. including Matrix.cpp does resolve the problem, but I know that that's a bad practice. So, what am I supposed to do and why?

Thank you very much!

EDIT: i did a test. i threw in Matrix.h a function declration, Implemented it in Matrix.cpp and then used it in Map.cpp. it did work without including Matrix.cpp. It's only with things belonging to the Matrix class that things go crazy.

Comment: Some code will help us give you a precise solution. it certainly looks you are missing a declaration in your .h, matching what is defined in you cpp.

Comment: Why are you including Matrix.cpp instead of Matrix.h? If there's something there that should be "public", it should go to the .h, not the .cpp

Comment: I think the clue is 'including Matrix.cpp does resolve the problem'. Obviously adding `#include "Matrix.cpp"` would get around the problem of not actually compiling Matrix.cpp in the normal way.

Comment: john is probably right, "undefined reference" sounds like a linker error, not a compilation error.

Comment: I'm including both Matrix.h and Matrix.cpp in Map.h, which is then included in Map.cpp

Comment: Including Matrix.cpp in a Matrix.h file is wrong. You need to learn how to create multiple source file projects in Code Blocks. It's well explained in the manual.

Comment: Have you perhaps declared the crucial non-working function `static`? I think the time is approaching when you are going to have to post your code, and that means all of it (or at least a big enough portion, that still has the problem you're experiencing).

Comment: No. But the Matrix class uses templtes (this all project is for me to learn them).i'd really like to post the code but the machine with the code is offline and can't go on line.

Comment: Aha! Template code only works if you put it in header files. You shouldn't be writing Matirx.cpp at all. That's the problem!

Comment: Oh god, I'm so sorry for having wasted all your time! So the whole class implementation goea in the header?

Comment: No problem, glad it was sorted in the end. There's more detail to this, you might want to read up on 'explicit template instantiation' but essentially the usual answer is to put all template code in header files. This is a [FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.12)

Answer (score 0):

Probably your problem is that you forgot to compile Matrix.cpp. This seems to be a surprisingly (to me) common mistake. How are you invoking your compiler?

Comment: I'm simply using code blocks, using the default "compile" button. It's MinGW

Comment: OK, I'm not familar with code blocks, but have you created a 'project'? Have you added both your .cpp files to the project?

Comment: Yes. And it compiled everything when I just had Matrix.cpp and Matrix.h

Comment: Well, I'm stumped. Forget all the language advice you are getting, it's clearly an issue with how you are using code blocks, but unless we see some screen shots I'm not sure how else to help.

Comment: i can't send you screens- the machine has no internet access and I'm writing from an iPad. i take your advice and see if I can make codeblocks compile that .cpp file, if that is the issue

Comment: @fedepiz, your project should look like this [screen shot](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Creating_a_new_project#Removing_a_file) with Matrix.cpp and Map.cpp listed under Sources. If your's does look like that then I'm really stumped and I'll take back what I said earlier.

Answer (score 0):

First I'll ask the obvious; have you `#include`ed `Map.h` in `Map.cpp`?

I would also point out that `Map.h` may not need to include `Matrix.h` at all.  If your only references to a `Matrix` in `Map.h` are pointer/reference arguments then you can simply forward declare the class:

```
// forward declare some currently unknown type "Matrix"
class Matrix;

class Map
{
public: 
    void SomeOperation( const Matrix& matrix );
};
```

As long as the argument is a pointer or reference type then the compiler does not need to know the size of a `Matrix` and thus everything just works.  This is better than including more headers in your .h files if you can do it.  Then you will include both `Matrix.h` and `Map.h` in your `Map.cpp` file.

Comment: I did include Map.h I also threw a forword declaration hoping that it would work automagically. it failed

Answer (score 0):

You might want to include both .h files in the  compilation, in order of need to have definitions work out, instead of through each other.

Then you should link to Matrix.o, based on the assumption that you are defining a symbol in Matrix.cpp that is needed to compile Map.cpp. Is this what is happening?

Comment: In Matrix.cpp I'm implementing all definitions of Matrix.h Map.cpp does get the .h definitions but fails to get the .cpp implementation, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Simple rules:-

1. Use guards in header files like:-

   ## ifndef MATRIX_H

## define MATRIX_H

...
... header file things
...

## endif

1. Have all class definitions/other declarations in header file. Definitions in related .cpp files.
2. Always try to avoid including one header file from another header file as far as possible.
   An extern declaration will do most of the times.
   Linked will automatically resolve the reference.
3. It is ok to include a header file from .cpp file. But here also, most of the times things do only with an extern declaration.

Comment: That's not good advice, in a big library that you have modules using other modules, it's best to include headers in other headers/source code so that when you change one module and thus its header, you don't need to go through ALL the files that used it and change your `extern` statements.